# UseFetch returns Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

When I'm using this useFetch hook my application shows a blank screen and returns:

> Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is
> a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix,
> cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup
> function.

I don't understand why it goes wrong.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function useFetch(url) {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async function () {
      try {
        setLoading(true);
        const response = await fetch(url, {
          method: "GET"
        });
        const data = await response.json();
        setData(data);
      } catch (err) {
        setError(err);
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    })();
  }, [url]);

  return { data, error, loading };
}

export const useFetchCarById = (testId) =>
  useFetch(
    `https://localhost/cars/${testId}`
  );

export default function Foo() {
  const { cars, car } = useContext(Context);
  const { data, error, loading } = useFetchCarById(car);

  return (
    <div>
      {data && data.map((x) => <p>{x.startTime}</p>)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: The code you show here is correct

Comment: The car in the Context is continuously changes value. Maybe is there the problem.

Comment: Fetches need to be canceled.  That is your memory leak.  The fetch is completing and after the component is unmounted.  Implement a cancelable promise if you insist on using `fetch` or use a library like `axios` that has them natively built in.